# How to fix compiler errors in SAPI 5.1 Header Files

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, text-to-speech, sapi

I got a lot of errors from SAPI 5.1 provided header files and cannot figure out how to fix those problems.

Following is a simple Text to Speech program from [Microsoft’s How to Video Presentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualc/bb924350).  The presenter said, if you have installed the most updated packages, you will have no problem compile this program.  But he is using Video Studio 2005; apparently the “most updated” refers a few years ago when the presentation was given.

I think these errors are caused version miss match.  I am using Windows XP SP3.  I have Visual Studio 2008 SP1, Visual Studio 2008 SDK 1.1, Windows SDK v6.0A(come with VS2008), Windows SDK v7.0 and SAPI 5.1.  Can someone help me figure out these problems?

TTSdemo.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <sapi.h>
#include <sphelper.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    int i;
    ULONG n;
    HRESULT hr;
    std::wstring args;
    CComPtr<ISpObjecToken> token;
    CComPtr<ISpVoice> tts;
    CoInitialize(0);

    for (i = 1, args = L""; i < argc; i++ )
    {
        args.append( argv[i] );
        args.append( L" " );
    }

    tts.CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice);
    hr = SpGetDefaultTokenFromCategoryId(SPCAT_VOICES, &token, FALSE);
    hr = tts->SetVoice(token);

    if (args.length() == 0 )
        std::wcout << L"Enter @<text file name> or <text to speak>" << STD::endl;
    else if ( args(0) == L'@' )
        tts->Speak(args.c_str() + 1, SPF_IS_FILENAME | SPF_ASYNC, &n);
    else
        tts->Speak(args.c_str(), SPF_IS_XML | SPF_ASYNC, &n);

    tts->WaitUntilDone(-1);

    tts.Release();
    token.Release();

    CoUninitialize();

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler errors

> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\spdebug.h(274) :
>   warning C4996: 'wcscpy': This function or variable may be unsafe.
>   Consider using wcscpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
>
> c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 9.0\vc\include\string.h(252)
>   : see declaration of 'wcscpy'
>
> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\sphelper.h(769) :
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\sphelper.h(1419) :
>   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int
>
> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\sphelper.h(2373) :
>   error C2065: 'psz' : undeclared identifier
>
> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\sphelper.h(2559) :
>   error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'CSpDynamicString'
>   to 'SPPHONEID *' No user-defined-conversion operator available that
>   can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
>
> c:\program files\microsoft speech sdk 5.1\include\sphelper.h(2633) :
>   error C2664: 'wcslen' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'SPPHONEID *'
>   to 'const wchar_t *'
>           Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast

Comment: The downloadable version of SAPI is getting quite old.  Old software doesn't behave like old wine.  Pray tell, show +/- 5 lines of code around sphelper.h, line #769.

Comment: try copy the definitions from the SAPI headers from Windows SDK 6.1 or higher.

Answer (score 3):

Please use `"\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A"` or 7.0 or 7.0A whatever latest available on your computer.

The SAPI DLL's and libs + header files are there, compatible for VS2008

Enjoy.

Comment: This is the method I used to fix all those errors and it worked perfectly.