# Speech recognition command C++ in SAPI?

Tags: c++, speech-recognition, sapi

I have spent hours looking for this and can't figure it out. I have a program that I have made which I would like to add voice recognition to (all it does is a few simple commands like time, date, things like that...it's just for fun) and I know I have some form of SAPI on my computer because I had to include sapi.h to get the voice synthesis to work (and that's works fine by the way) but I can't figure out for the life of me how to use the voice recognition.

It appears people have already asked about C++ voice recognition on here so I apologize if this is just a duplicate but none of the others seemed to answer my question, perhaps I'm just missing something (I'm fairly new to C++ so it's very possible) but I could really use some help here.

Thanks a bunch!

----edit----

The code in the link has an issue on my computer, it can't find the file "atlbase.h" which then of course is causing all sorts of other problems (hopefully these will all be resolved when I fix the atlbase.h problem). I found this site which seems to offer an explanation which shows up on quite a few other sites and appears to work, but I don't know how to get to the file that everyone is changing.

https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/12757/error-cannot-find-atlbaseh-when-compiling-in-vs201.html

Could someone please help me as to where the file they're all changing is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SAPI: Speech to Text example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16547349/sapi-speech-to-text-example)

Comment: I just tried the code in that example and I'm getting a few errors in the sphelper.h file, it says cannot open source file "atlbase.h" as well as "CComPtr is not a template". The second is probably defined in "atlbase.h", but how do I get this file?

Comment: About atlbase read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898287/c-include-atlbase-h-is-not-found. Overall it's better to use in-sdk SAPI, not distributed SAPI, read about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7224902/how-to-fix-compiler-errors-in-sapi-5-1-header-files